# What is the use of IBoutlet in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am very well know about full form of IB but i want to know the exact use of IBoutlet

what is the use of IBoutlet in ios in iPhone apps ?

Comment: [Apple Doc: Outlets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html)

Comment: Adding a button to a view enables user interactivity. An IBOutlet helps connect the button control to the code to make the button accessible programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a variable or a property as an IBOutlet to relate it to the objects that you define in your XIB.    ....

Think of the view defined in the XIB as a separate routines that are hidden to your code.
The objects - UItextfields, UIImageview etc. that are defined in the XIB are created outside your code (.m ) file IBOutlet allows you to refer to them in  your code.

Answer (score 1):

`IBOutlet` is macro that define variables and methods that are related to in `Interface Builder`.